# Input file field empty after uploading with jquery file upload

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, input, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to upload files and save the links in to my database with the [jquery file upload](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_blueimp.md) plugin and the [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle) in Symfony.

I have an input file field in my form like this:

```
<input class="form-control" id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" multiple />
```

In my jQuery I have this:

```
$('#form-Entity').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        $("#submitentity").on('click', function () {
            data.submit();
        });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#form-Entity')[0].submit();
    }
});
```

First I prevent the form from submitting. Then I upload the files. But when they are uploaded and I want to submit the form, the input files field is empty so I don't get anything in my backend ... . Also when I select images my input field still says 'no files selected'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a list and every time a file is uploaded I add it to the list. At the end, before submitting the form I set the value of the hidden input field with the list.